# UITapGestureRecognizer for UILabel inside of a StackView

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have a Stack View with two labels, one of which once tapped, suppose to lead to another view.

Here the code of my UIView subclass where labels and a StackView are setup:

```
    import UIKit
    import SnapKit

class WelcomeView: UIView {

weak var coordinator: MainCoordinator?

private let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "backGroundImage")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    return imageView
}()

private let questionLabel: UILabel = {
    let questionLabel = UILabel()
    questionLabel.text = "Don't have an Account?"
    questionLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next Regular", size: 17)
    questionLabel.textColor = .black

    return questionLabel
}()

private let signUpLabel: UILabel = {
    let signUpLabel = UILabel()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.signUpTapped(tapGesture:)))

    signUpLabel.text = "Sign Up"
    signUpLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next Regular", size: 17)
    signUpLabel.textColor = .black
    signUpLabel.highlightedTextColor = .link
    signUpLabel.isHighlighted = true

    signUpLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    signUpLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    return signUpLabel
}()

lazy var signUpstackView: UIStackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [questionLabel, signUpLabel])

    stackView.axis = .horizontal        
    stackView.alignment = .fill
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.spacing = 8
    stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    return stackView
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubViews()

}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    addSubViews()

}    

func addSubViews() {

    self.backgroundColor = .white
    self.addSubview(imageView)
    self.addSubview(btnSignIn)
    self.addSubview(signUpstackView)
    setConstraints()

}

func setConstraints() {
    imageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.edges.equalToSuperview()
    }

    btnSignIn.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in

        make.height.equalTo(60)
        make.bottomMargin.equalTo(-50)
        make.leftMargin.equalTo(28)
        make.rightMargin.equalTo(-28)
    }

    signUpstackView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.height.equalTo(24)
        make.centerX.equalTo(self)
        make.top.equalTo(btnSignIn).offset(70)
    }
}
}
```

I added UITapGestureRecognizer in **signUpLabel**.

And here is the code from my ViewController containing my IBAction function **signUpTapped** which is specified in UITapGestureRecognizer:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var welcomeView = WelcomeView()

override func loadView() {
    view = welcomeView

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

    @IBAction func signUpTapped(tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Tapped")
    }

}
```

For some reason nothing is happened when I try to click on my SignUp Label. Is this an issue because my UILabel is inside of a StackView?

Answer (score 0):

You need

**Sol 1**

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.signUpTapped(tapGesture:)))
```

then inside the view class

```
 weak var delegate:ViewController?

  @objc func signUpTapped(tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Tapped")
    delegate?.tapped()
}
```

---

```
var welcomeView = WelcomeView()

override func loadView() {
   welcomeView.delegate = self
   view = welcomeView 
}
func tapped(){}
```

**Sol 2**

```
weak var delegate:ViewController?
init(frame: CGRect,delegate:ViewController) { 
  super.init(frame: frame)
  self.delegate = delegate
  addSubViews() 
}
```

With

```
let tap = delegate(target:delegate!, action: #selector(delegate!.signUpTapped(tapGesture:)))
```

and inside the vc

```
@objc func signUpTapped(tapGesture:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Tapped")
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately Sol1 did help. After implementing it, nothing still happened when I try to tap on "Sign Up" Label. 


I has not been able to implement Sol2 due to error pop up when I tried to modify my override init() method in UIView subclass by adding "delegate:ViewController" as input parameter.
Error - "Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass".

Comment: Maybe problem somehow in the constraints that had been implemented on StackView? That somehow when I tap on "SignUp" label I just tap on StackView bounds and not on a label itself? And the code just not get triggered?